# Snapshot Image can't be used as stage icon

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to set an image from a stage snapshot as the stage icon.

The following code demonstrates it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IconTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new ImageView(generateIcon(32))));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.getIcons().setAll(generateIcon(32));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static Image generateIcon(int dimension) throws IOException {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null)));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, dimension, dimension);

    return scene.snapshot(new WritableImage(dimension, dimension));
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the stage icon is not a red square. **Why is that?** Loading from a file always works, generating the image using AWT works, too.

Workaround:

```
BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(dimension, dimension, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(scene.snapshot(new WritableImage(dimension, dimension)), bimg);
SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimg, new WritableImage(dimension, dimension));
```

Comment: How bizarre.  I tried it on OS X and get the same behavior, it doesn't work without the workaround, but it works with the workaround `return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshotImage, null), null)`.  So whatever the bug is, it is not OS specific.  If I were you, I'd be inclined to ignore it, go with the workaround, and move on...