# How to use a FontAwesomeIconView object as a Stage's icon?

Tags: javafx, font-awesome

I am using [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) for many icons throughout my application. I would like to use them as icons for my `Stage` as well.

Since `FontAwesomeIconView` extends `GlyphIcon` which extends `Text`, I can not use it as an `Image` directly.

Is there a way to create a usable `Image` from a `Text` object?

I have tried to use `snapshot`, but I am not familiar with that method and end up with the standard "empty" icon on my stage.

Here is the MCVE I have so far:

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontAwesomeIconExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Convert the FontAwesomeIconView node to an Image
        FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.ID_CARD_ALT);
        WritableImage icon = iconView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

        primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(100);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: screenshot]

---

Is it possible to use a node snapshot as a stage icon? Or is there a better method of converting the `FontAwesomeIconView` for this purpose?

> **EDIT:**

I have tried both Sedrick's and JKostikiadis's methods and both give similar results for me.

---

**Sedrick's:**

```
    // Convert the FontAwesomeIconView node to an Image
    FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.AMAZON);
    WritableImage icon = iconView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(icon, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**JKostikiadis's:**

```
    FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.AMAZON);
    WritableImage writableImg = iconView.snapshot(null, null);
    Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImg, null), null);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(img);
```

[image: screenshot]

---

I believe they both accomplish essentially the same thing (with the sizing of the `Image` resulting in different displayed icons).

What I do not understand now, is why this is the icon it is producing for me and not them...

> I am running Windows 7 and JDK 1.8.0_161.

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029931/snapshot-image-cant-be-used-as-stage-icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Sedrick's answer, another (shorter) solution could be to just create an Image (javafx package) and add it stage icons :

```
FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.AMAZON);
WritableImage writableImg = iconView.snapshot(null, null);
Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImg, null), null);
primaryStage.getIcons().add(img);
```

P.S A relative post could be found here : [Snapshot Image can't be used as stage icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029931/snapshot-image-cant-be-used-as-stage-icon)

**Edit**:

For some reason, the version 8.15 of the FontawesomeFx require the FontAwesomeIconView to be added on a Scene in order to initialize its content, something that is not necessary to do on the newest version of FontawesomeFx. So, in my opinion, you have to either upgrade your FontawesomeFx version or to add the FontAwesomeIconView on a Scene and after to take the snapshot. Like this :

```
FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.ID_CARD_ALT);
Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(iconView));
WritableImage writableImg = iconView.snapshot(null, null);
Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImg, null), null);
```

Here is the result (using 8.5 version):

[image]

Comment: I have tried this method, but regardless of which `FontAwesomeIcon` I use, I get an odd "U" icon for the `Stage`.

Comment: My current version of FontAwesomeIcon is fontawesomeFx 8.9, try to update your version and let me know.I will try to download your version and check it again later.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded to v8.9 and all is well now.

Comment: It seems v8.9 does not include all the same icons as 8.15. So the search continues...

Comment: @Zephyr yes that is true, thats why if you want to continue using 8.15 you could use the solution displayed on my edit. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: They might have change the name of some icons so you will need to find the cheatsheet of your version and search for the icon you are looking for..

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to track down the Glyph Browser for 8.9, but can't find that either. I might need to revert back to 8.15. Thanks, mate. Your workaround for 8.15 does work.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. The goal is to get an `InputStream`. I was able to do that using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(icon, null);` to get a bufferedImage. From there I used `ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", s);` to get a `byte array`. I used to `byte array` to get an `InputStream`.

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FontAwesomeIconExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            // Simple Interface
            VBox root = new VBox(10);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

            // Convert the FontAwesomeIconView node to an Image
            FontAwesomeIconView iconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.AMAZON);
            WritableImage icon = iconView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
            BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(icon, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", s);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.toByteArray());

            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(is, 16, 16, false, false));

            // Show the stage
            primaryStage.setWidth(300);
            primaryStage.setHeight(100);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FontAwesomeIconExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

[image]
[image]

**This is worth noting from the javadoc.**

> The images should be different sizes of the same image and the best size will be chosen, eg. 16x16, 32x32.

Comment: I've updated my question. I tried both answers so far and they both have similar results for me, neither of which is the same as yours. Even doing a copy/paste of the complete code in your answer gives me the screenshot I've added to my question.

Comment: I used Java 8 for this answer. What version are you using?

Comment: Also fontawesomeFx 8.9

Comment: I have FontAwesomeFX 8.15 and JDK 1.8_161. I do not see FAFX v8.9 available for download to test. The lastes I see for Java 8 is 8.15.

Comment: Thank you, Sedrick. Your method works perfectly with v8.9 as well. I accepted  JKostikiadis's answer, though, as it's a bit cleaner and he could use the points more than you :)